# how to insert a date selected in datepicker in a mySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I've searched this and other sites, but I only find methods to insert a manual date value or to use a datepicker. Now i want to insert a date from my datepicker into a date field in mySQL.

```
$date = $_POST['calendar2b'];

$sql4 = "Insert into geschiedenis(login_fk, status_fk, code_fk, uitleendatum,inleverdatum,uitleenuur,inleveruur) Values ('".$login."','beschikbaar','".$code."',Now(),DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 DAY),curtime(),curtime())";
```

If I use now this works, but I need to use the date from a datepicker.

Comment: 1) What will your datepicker return?

Comment: 2) You declared `$date` but you haven't used it in your query

Comment: guten Tag! Should `$date` be going into uitleendatum, or inleverdatum?

Comment: check the format of $date.....

Comment: I know i have to declare date, and i do use it but when i declare it, my query returns 0000-00-00. When i use the now() statement it gives today. But this is a reservation form so i need to be able to choose a date...

Comment: I've run some tests, it appears that my datepicker doesn't return a value : my code now :